# How to detect one by one click interval with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, timeout

I have a little question, is there any option to detect clicks interval and set for them any condition. For example if i click one by one in one second interval i can do something, and if i click again after 0.5s i can make something else? I have no idea how to write this so i can't add any example on my code only this vision, also i can't find this solution in other therds, can you help me?

```
var clicks=0;
function myClickFunction(event){
    clicks++;
}
$(function(){
    $("#something").on("click",myClickFunction);
        if (click == )){

        }   
    });
});
```

Much thx for answer!

Comment: Are you asking how to detect double-clicks?

Comment: no, i need to detect time interval between first and second click, and if it's f.e. 1s do something, and if it's 0,5s do something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lastClickTime;

function testTime(time){
    switch (true) {
        case (time < 500):
            alert("less than 500ms!");
            break;
        case (time < 1000):
            alert("less than 1000ms but not 500ms!");
            break;
        default: 
            alert("you sure click slow!");
            break;
    }
}

$("#something").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newTime = new Date();
    if(lastClickTime !== undefined) {
         testTime(newTime - lastClickTime);
    } 
   lastClickTime = newTime;
});
```

This is a quick way to do it, but creates some globals. It should put you on the right path though!

A switch might help you keep track of all the different cases you want.

Comment: this is awesome and works perfect, but i have one problem, this not work for the first click :)

Comment: You can add an else statement on the undefined test to capture the first click.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind `click` and `dblclick` functions. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) and watch out this:

> Note: Although demonstrated in the next example, it is inadvisable to
>   bind handlers to both the click and dblclick events for the same
>   element. The sequence of events triggered varies from browser to
>   browser, with some receiving two click events before the dblclick and
>   others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum time between clicks
>   that is detected as a double click) can vary by operating system and
>   browser, and is often user-configurable.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually track the time of the last click. Then every time your event handler is called compare the current time to the stored one.

Some pseudo code:

```
last_click_time = 0
onClick () {
  if ( last_click_time == 0 ) {
    // first click
    last_click_time = time.now();
  } else {
    time_difference = time.now () - last_click_time;
    if ( time_difference == 0.5 ) {
      // half a second since last click
    } else if ( time_difference == 1 ) {
      // one second since last click
    }
    ...
    last_click_time = time.now ();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact control of timing you could just check the milliseconds on the current machine.

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPLrw/1/)

**Html:**

```
<a id="asd">yo</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#asd").click(function(){
    var latest = $(this).data("time") || 0;
    var now = +new Date();
    var diff = now-latest;
    if(diff < 500) alert("That was faster than 0.5 seconds!");
    if(diff > 1000 && diff < 1500) alert("That was between 1.0 and 1.5 seconds.");
    $(this).data("time",now);
});
```